# relation between indices of a tensor and its vectorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, tensors

Assume three-mode tensor $A \in R^{n_1 \times n_2 \times n_3}$ and its vectorization as $a=vec(A)$. What is the relation between the index elements of tensor $A$ and vector $a$? Specifically, I would like to know which element of tensor $A$ is correspond to the $i$th element of vector $a$.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that you're following [this convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_reshaping#Vectorization) of vectorization. I also assume that your indexing starts at one, which (unfortunately perhaps) is a bit more common in mathematical literature on tensors.

The $(i,j,k)$ entry of the tensor $A$ is mapped to the $p$th vector entry, with 
$$
p = 1 + (i-1) + n_1(j-1) + n_1n_2(k-1).
$$
Going in the opposite direction, we find that the $p$th vector entry corresponds to the $(i,j,k)$ element of the tensor $A$, with
$$
i = 1 + ([p-1] \bmod n_1), \\
j = 1 + ([p - i - 1] \bmod n_1n_2) = 1 + \lfloor[p - n_1n_2(k-1) - 1]/n_1\rfloor, \\
k = 1 + \lfloor (p-1)/(n_1n_2)\rfloor.
$$
As the two forms of $j$ indicate, there are two general ways to compute these indices (for tensors of arbitrary order). You can either compute these indices from left to right using the modulo operator or from right to left using integer division.

Comment: These equations simplify with $0$-indexing.

Comment: @J.G. They certainly do

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. It seems there is an issue with the $j$ index formula. Assume that $n_1=3$,$n_2=2$ and $n_3=2$. For index $p=6$, the left formula for $j$ gives $4$ while the right formula gives $3$ which both of them are not correct. Would you please give a more explanation on how you obtain the formulas?

Comment: @user51780 See my latest edit; I had an off by 1 error. As J.G. notes, this all becomes much easier if you use $0$-indexing instead (i.e. count $0,1,\dots,n-1$). If I find time, I can give a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for a tensor $A \in \mathbb{R}^{r_1 \times \cdots \times r_m} $, an entry $a_{i_1, \cdots, i_m}$ of $A$ maps to the $j$-th entry of vec$(A)$, in which $j=1+\sum_{k=1}^m(i_k-1)\prod_{k'=1}^{k-1}r_{k'}$. You can understand this vectorization as stacking the model-1 fibers of $A$.